# How do I reference an object/value from another function efficiently in Java

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I am a young programmer, and I am working on a java plugin for a game and I ran into a problem where I can't get an XYZ coordinate from another event's variable, to my current event. Making the variable public would cause major problems for my code and putting all the values in an array works, but it doesn't feel right, and I think I am using to much energy where it isn't needed.

**My Relevant Code:**

```
ArrayList<Location> GenLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();

public void firstEvent(){
        for(int i = 0; i < GenLocations.size(); i++) {
            Location L = GenLocations.get(i);
            if(event.getClickedBlock().getLocation().equals(L)) {
               //Non-relevant code...
            }
        }
}

public void secondEvent(){
                if(searchInventory(event.getWhoClicked().getInventory(),"Too big name", 8, true)) {
                    /* Here is where I want the correct XYZ coord from GenLocations.get(i). It is hard to tell 
                    whether GenLocations.get(i) is the right position without 
                    if(event.getClickedBlock().getLocation().equals(L)){} or going through a bunch of if statements 
                    comparing the data of arrays with the current event which is 
                    pain staking long and possibly inefficient /*
                    
                }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using tons of for loops or am I doing it the way I should be?

Comment: Java programming conventions use upper case letters for class names, and lower case letters for variables and methods (gemLocations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the 2 methods are in the same class, not sure if you are looking to store all the locations or just one. If you are trying to store one variable you  can create a member variable in the class say `Location firstEventLocation` and when you find in Location in `firstEvent()` store it in the local variable `firstEventLocation = GenLocations.get(index)`. The then `secondEvent` you can reference the first location from the variable `firstEventLocation`, just be sure to check that firstEventLocation is not null if there is a chance it could be. One other small note, try to stick to java naming conventions variable names for should start lowercase letters, `GenLocations` under naming conventions should be `genLocations`

Comment: I have multiple instances of the same object and the locations of them are in that array. I needed to take that location of the relevant instance out of the array in order for my code to work. The problem is, is that I cannot get the location out of the array efficiently, and I am concerned that I am doing it wrong.  Also, the GenLocations is named that way because it is easier to get the arrays out of the variables easily, but I'll be sure to name my arrays that way in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is locating the index of the array that contains the location data, then introduce another data structure to track the index.

For instance, a HashMap, keyed on the object and containing the index within the array as its value item, would help you efficiently find your item.